# Desugaring fails after adding libraries

Tags: android

I've added two libraries to my application and now desugaring fails. The libraries in question are

```
implementation 'io.jenetics:jpx:2.0.0'
implementation 'stax:stax:1.2.0'
```

The complete error message I'm getting is

```
Class or interface javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException required for desugaring of try-with-resources is not found.
Stack trace:
com.android.tools.r8.errors.a: Class or interface javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException required for desugaring of try-with-resources is not found.
    at com.android.tools.r8.errors.a.a(SourceFile:7)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.O.b(SourceFile:59)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.O.a(SourceFile:435)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.O.a(SourceFile:384)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.V0.a(SourceFile:2)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.T0.d(SourceFile:3)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.V0.a(SourceFile:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.U0.a(SourceFile:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.D.b(SourceFile:7)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.O.b(SourceFile:35)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(SourceFile:37)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(SourceFile:30)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:69)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:322)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:66)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractListeningExecutorService.submit(AbstractListeningExecutorService.java:36)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(SourceFile:31)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(SourceFile:3)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(SourceFile:36)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(SourceFile:32)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.O.a(SourceFile:335)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(D8.java:39)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(D8.java:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.V.a(SourceFile:34)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:11)
    at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:116)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BaseDexingTransform.process(DexingTransform.kt:297)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BaseDexingTransform.processNonIncrementally(DexingTransform.kt:244)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BaseDexingTransform.doTransform(DexingTransform.kt:154)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BaseDexingTransform.access$doTransform(DexingTransform.kt:71)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BaseDexingTransform$transform$1.invoke(DexingTransform.kt:108)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BaseDexingTransform$transform$1.invoke(DexingTransform.kt:71)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.BlocksUtilsKt.recordArtifactTransformSpan(BlocksUtils.kt:33)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.dependency.BaseDexingTransform.transform(DexingTransform.kt:102)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformer.transform(DefaultTransformer.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory$TransformerExecution.execute(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:332)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:159)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:85)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory$2.lambda$call$2(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.fireTransformListeners(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:269)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.access$300(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory$2.call(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:178)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory$2.call(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:175)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.lambda$doTransform$0(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:175)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.lambda$withWorkspace$0(ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:81)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.withFileLock(LockOnDemandCrossProcessCacheAccess.java:90)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.withFileLock(DefaultCacheAccess.java:191)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.withFileLock(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:177)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.withFileLock(DefaultCacheFactory.java:201)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.withWorkspace(ImmutableTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:76)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.lambda$withWorkspace$0(AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:56)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4718)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3445)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2194)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2153)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2043)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3851)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4713)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.withWorkspace(AbstractCachingTransformationWorkspaceProvider.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.doTransform(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:175)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.access$000(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory$1.invoke(DefaultTransformerInvocationFactory.java:141)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.CacheableInvocation$1.invoke(CacheableInvocation.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNode$ChainedTransformationNode$1.lambda$transform$0(TransformationNode.java:234)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Success.flatMap(Try.java:157)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNode$ChainedTransformationNode$1.transform(TransformationNode.java:233)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNode$ArtifactTransformationStepBuildOperation.call(TransformationNode.java:275)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNode$ArtifactTransformationStepBuildOperation.call(TransformationNode.java:255)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNode$ChainedTransformationNode.execute(TransformationNode.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.WorkNodeExecutor.execute(WorkNodeExecutor.java:27)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:370)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:357)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:350)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.r8.errors.a: Class or interface javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException required for desugaring of try-with-resources is not found.
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:552)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:513)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.FluentFuture$TrustedFuture.get(FluentFuture.java:86)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.R0.a(SourceFile:8)
        ... 123 more
    [CIRCULAR REFERENCE:com.android.tools.r8.errors.a: Class or interface javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException required for desugaring of try-with-resources is not found.]
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.a: Class or interface javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException required for desugaring of try-with-resources is not found.
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.optimize.k.a(SourceFile:1187)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.optimize.k.m(SourceFile:9)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.O.a(SourceFile:1112)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.O.a(SourceFile:752)
    at com.android.tools.r8.ir.conversion.O.b(SourceFile:56)
    ... 143 more
```

Any suggestions about how to fix that?

The complete source code can be found [here](https://github.com/tonsV2/open-run-tracker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding `minifyEnabled true` to my `release` `buildTypes`.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

I'm honestly not sure why this works. But I'm guessing it might strip the problem causing code from the apk. If anyone can shed light on the subject I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, while using Android Studio **BumbleBee** and my **Gradle** **version** being **7.2**, this is how I resolved this error below;

```
com.android.tools.r8.internal.YI0: One or more instruction is preventing default interface method from being desugared: java.lang.Double it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.objects.Reference2DoubleMap.getOrDefault(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Double)
```

1. In your **project files**, go to your **app** folder and open
   **build.gradle**
2. At **compileOptions**  I added the line **coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true**
3. At **dependencies** I added the line **coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'**
4. **Save** the changes you made then **Build** your project again. This should resolve it.

By the end of the day your app's **build.gradle** would closely resemble the screenshot below.

[image]

Read more about **Java 8+ API desugaring support (Android Gradle Plugin 4.0.0+)** on **Android**'s **website** here https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support